# Looping though an object in Angular and using the key inside a ng-show

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

i am creating a simple Angular.js tabbing box which changes the box that is active accoring to a value 'tab' that is used inside ng-show on the elements.
This is working fine, however, at the moment I am writing all the HTML statically and I would rather cut down my code into a simple ng-repeat loop to loop through all the divs.

This is easy enough in PHP as I would use a foreach loop and use the key to generate the tab number, I just can't seem to do this in Angular. Here is my code at the moment:

```
<div id="services-box-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 1" ng-class="{'active' : tab == 1}">Rewards</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 2" ng-class="{'active' : tab == 2}">Community</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 3" ng-class="{'active' : tab == 3}">Partners</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 4" ng-class="{'active' : tab == 4}">Jobs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 5" ng-class="{'active' : tab == 5}">Volunteering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 6" ng-class="{'active' : tab == 6}">Feedback</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 7" ng-class="{'active' : tab == 7}">Gallery</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="services-content-boxes">                   
                    <div ng-show="tab == 1">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h3>{{serviceBoxes.rewards.title}}</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                {{serviceBoxes.rewards.text}}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-7">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                  
                    <div ng-show="tab == 2">dwd</div>
                    <div ng-show="tab == 3">d</div>
                    <div ng-show="tab == 4">df</div>
                    <div ng-show="tab == 5">gr</div>
                    <div ng-show="tab == 6">r</div>
                    <div ng-show="tab == 7">rg</div>                    
                </div>

 controller('servicesController', function($scope, $location, joomlaService) {  
    $scope.serviceBoxes = {};       
    joomlaService.getArticleDetails(21).then(function(articleReturnData) {          
        $scope.serviceBoxes.rewards = articleReturnData;
    });
    joomlaService.getArticleDetails(22).then(function(articleReturnData) {          
        $scope.serviceBoxes.community = articleReturnData;
    });     
    joomlaService.getArticleDetails(23).then(function(articleReturnData) {          
        $scope.serviceBoxes.partners = articleReturnData;
    });     
    joomlaService.getArticleDetails(24).then(function(articleReturnData) {          
        $scope.serviceBoxes.jobs = articleReturnData;
    });     
    joomlaService.getArticleDetails(25).then(function(articleReturnData) {          
        $scope.serviceBoxes.volunteering = articleReturnData;
    });     
    joomlaService.getArticleDetails(26).then(function(articleReturnData) {          
        $scope.serviceBoxes.feedback = articleReturnData;
    });     
    joomlaService.getArticleDetails(27).then(function(articleReturnData) {          
        $scope.serviceBoxes.gallery = articleReturnData;
    });         
});
```

What I want to do is loop through the serviceBoxes object and dynamically create the ng-show condition (tab == i) using the key, which should increment each time (1, 2, 3, 4, etc). I don't know how I go about this using Angular. It would cut down my code considerably so feel it is necessary.

Can anyone point out how this is done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [angular-ui bootstrap Tabset directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs).

```
  <tabset>
    <tab ng-repeat="serviceBox in serviceBoxes" heading="{{serviceBox.title}}" active="serviceBox.active">
      {{serviceBox.text}}
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

Thus your view is clean and tidy.

And your controller will look like:

```js
controller('servicesController', function($scope, $location, joomlaService) {
  $scope.serviceBoxes = [];
  joomlaService.getArticleDetails(21).then(function(articleReturnData) {
    $scope.serviceBoxes.push(articleReturnData);
  });
  joomlaService.getArticleDetails(22).then(function(articleReturnData) {
    $scope.serviceBoxes.push(articleReturnData);
  });
  joomlaService.getArticleDetails(23).then(function(articleReturnData) {
    $scope.serviceBoxes.push(articleReturnData);
  });
  joomlaService.getArticleDetails(24).then(function(articleReturnData) {
    $scope.serviceBoxes.push(articleReturnData);
  });
  joomlaService.getArticleDetails(25).then(function(articleReturnData) {
    $scope.serviceBoxes.push(articleReturnData);
  });
  joomlaService.getArticleDetails(26).then(function(articleReturnData) {
    $scope.serviceBoxes.push(articleReturnData);
  });
  joomlaService.getArticleDetails(27).then(function(articleReturnData) {
    $scope.serviceBoxes.push(articleReturnData);
  });
});
```

Comment: You could also add the $index parameter into the ng-click($index), that will return the current item being clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="serviceBox in serviceBoxes"><a href="#" ng-click="itemClicked($index)" ng-class="{'active' : $index == selectedIndex}">{{serviceBox.title}}</a></li>
</ul>


<div ng-repeat="serviceBox in serviceBoxes" ng-show="tab == {{selectedIndex}}">{{serviceBox.contents}}</div>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.selectedIndex = 0; // Default selected index, use -1 for no selection

 $scope.itemClicked = function ($index) {
    $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
  };
```

The ng-repeat directive loops through every element and makes a copy of the html element it's placed inside of. If there at 10 items to look through, you will have 10 html elements. It also you references to the index of the current element via $index.

ng-click will call the function on itemClicked(), passing in the current index through the $index reference that ng-repeat supplied. In our function we're using that parameter to set our $scope.selected to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried creating something similar. Try below code
I have hardcoded mapTab array.You can populate myTab using the corresponding values from $scope

In controller-

```
$scope.tab;
    $scope.mapTab=[{},{"1": "dwd"},{"2":"d"},{"3":"dwd"},{"4":"df"},{"5":"gr"},{"6":"r"},{"7":"rg"}];
```

In html--

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,val) in mapTab">
                <div ng-repeat="prop in val">
                    <div ng-show="tab==key">{{prop}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Demo--http://jsfiddle.net/RahulB007/HB7LU/9348/